# Show r Forecast Accuracy in Tableau

Tags: r, tableau-api

I've got the r code below that I'm running in tableau to forecast.

Does anyone know a good way to show the accuracy of my forecast in tableau, or to show the results of the r function accuracy(fcast,ts1Test) in tableau?

Code:

```
SCRIPT_REAL("library(forecast);
library(zoo);
l<-length(.arg1);
u<-.arg1[1:(l-.arg2[1])];
n<-length(u);
u[n]=.arg1[l];
jjearnts <- ts(na.approx(u),frequency=24);
fcast <- forecast(jjearnts, h=.arg2[1]);
append(u,fcast$mean, after = n)",
[SaleCount],[PeriodsToForecast])
```